# Bootstrap 4 dropdown with search

Tags: bootstrap-4

How to implement the `data-live-search="true"` in **bootstrap 4** dropdown?

Below link contained a good explanation, however it was for Bootstrap 3.

[Bootstrap 3 select](https://web.archive.org/web/20180425134632/https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Answer (score 25):

I could not find a standard control and had 0 intention to use a library such as bootstrap select so I custom made this widget. Bootstrap 4 allows you to add forms inside your dropdown which is what I have used here. I added a search box, used an input event to capture the text entered by the user inside the box, If the phrase entered by the user starts with the items inside the box, I show the items else I hide them. I also handle the click event on any item to change the text of the dropdown button

```js
//Initialize with the list of symbols
let names = ["BTC","XRP","ETH","BCH","ADA","XEM","LTC","XLM","TRX","MIOTA","DASH","EOS","XMR","NEO","QTUM","BTG","ETC","ICX","LSK","XRB","OMG","SC","BCN","ZEC","XVG","BCC","DCN","BTS","PPT","DOGE","BNB","KCS","STRAT","ARDR","SNT","STEEM","USDT","WAVES","VEN","DGB","KMD","DRGN","HSR","KIN","ETN","GNT","REP","VERI","ETHOS","RDD","ARK","XP","FUN","KNC","BAT","DCR","SALT","DENT","ZRX","PIVX","QASH","NXS","ELF","AE","FCT","POWR","REQ","AION","SUB","BTM","WAX","XDN","NXT","QSP","MAID","RHOC","GAS","LINK","GBYTE","MONA","SAN","ENG","ICN","BTCD","SYS","XZC","VEE","POE","TNB","PAY","DGD","WTC","PAC","ZCL","GNO","LEND","CVC","RDN","BNT","NEBL","GXS","ACT","DBC","ENJ","STORM","STORJ","GAME","VTC","COB","UKG","SKY","CND","SMART","NAV","CNX","XBY","MED","CMT","RPX","PLR","CTR","BAY","BLOCK","ANT","R","UBQ","SNM","MCO","AST","MANA","SNGLS","ITC","RCN","FLASH","AMB","DATA","EDG","ATM","XPA","DNT","RLC","PART","ADX","ST","TRIG","EMC2","WABI","BRD","ETP","BURST","XSH","DTR","BCO","WINGS","FUEL","ZEN","NULS","EMC","MOON","PPP","MGO","XCP","SRN","1ST","TNT","PPC","MOD","LBC","THC","LA","DCT","MLN","UTK","SPANK","RISE","CLOAK","XAS","EDO","CDT","DPY","QRL","WGR","MTL","GTO","AGRS","GVT","PRL","VIA","ADT","GRS","COSS","AEON","GRID","YOYOW","SHIFT","HST","VOX","MTH","INK","FTC","XSPEC","NYC","NLG","CFI","PRE","TRST","VIB","LUN","BNTY","SLS","GUP","EVX","SNOV","DLT","UNITY","JINN","MER","ECN","PURA","MINT","NLC2","POT","ZSC","TKN","HMQ","NMC","WRC","VIBE","AMP","DIME","PEPECASH","BITCNY","RVT","PPY","PASC","DAT","PRO","TIX","ION","BCPT","BLK","TAAS","COLX","NET","DMD","IOC","AIR","MDA","PAYX","MNX","STX","BITB","SIB","IXT","XEL","NMR","LRC","DRT","GRC","LMC","CRW","ELIX","HEAT","MSP","EXP","FAIR","XMY","SLR","OMNI","NEU","GOLOS","MUE","BTX","PHR","FLIXX","ONION","DIVX","HVN","PBL","OAX","XWC","MUSIC","ECC","BOT","ATB","DOVU","EAC","ARN","PKT","NEOS","ART","KICK","LKK","XRL","RADS","VRC","OK","VOISE","CREDO","POLL","SPRTS","TIPS","LINDA","PST","FLDC","NSR","PLBT","LOC","RBY","NXC","DBET","ZOI","HUSH","TGT","CAG","SBD","ALIS","PTOY","ECOB","XLR","COVAL","MYST","SWT","BIS","AVT","SNC","GCR","GAM","PINK","PRG","XNN","BLUE","QAU","BCAP","IFT","INCNT","POSW","FLO","IOP","XST","DNA","DTB","TIME","GEO","BMC","ORME","PIX","OTN","MYB","SPF","QWARK","OCT","ENRG","CRED","CLAM","ESP","CARBON","HDG","NIO","GMT","WILD","SOAR","WCT","PND","CAT","STAK","ODN","RMC","ABY","CURE","ICOS","BSD","BITUSD","OBITS","BBR","FRST","XPM","BET","XVC","SEQ","BCY","TX","DOPE","CSNO","CANN","XMCC","SUMO","WISH","OXY","SPR","BTM","TFL","BQ","DICE","LEO","OPT","UNO","NVST","SPHR","SNRG","XUC","PRIX","DBIX","PFR","PLU","NTRN","ATMS","SSS","SYNX","ALQO","PTC","BWK","1337","HYP","2GIVE","ETT","SEND","UFR","ZNY","RUP","MEME","DOT","DRP","GLD","REAL","GBX","BELA","TCC","VSX","CRC","BRX","VRM","CRB","SXC","LUX","ITNS","XAUR","AUR","UNIT","QRK","INXT","UFO","B2B","IXC","AC","START","KORE","BRK","BTDX","SCL","XBC","PIRL","IND","TZC","RIC","ARC","BUZZ","QVT","ZEIT","NVC","INN","BDL","HBT","HGT","HWC","REX","NOTE","EXCL","BLITZ","PURE","NOBL","MTNC","VIVO","FYP","BBT","CHC","XTO","ERO","APX","EDR","USNBT","VSL","CRAVE","EBST","ASTRO","TOA","FOR","ADST","CHIPS","VTR","BTCZ","BPL","ERC","808","PZM","PDC","TRUST","XMG","ZEPH","DYN","LIFE","PUT","BON","ADC","BUN","XCN","UNIFY","SMART","TRC","CREA","MAG","EGC","CVCOIN","EQT","WDC","ANC","GOOD","HOLD","FRD","ATS","B3","ELTCOIN","LDOGE","HUC","TKS","DGPT","FJC","SWIFT","ATL","XFT","REC","ONG","XGOX","PKB","MXT","ELLA","CFT","KRB","AHT","MBRS","DNR","PING","RKC","RNS","DCY","EBTC","YOC","GIM","MZC","MCAP","ZRC","BLU","ETBS","EFL","FST","NET","FLT","CTX","ARC","GCC","XCPO","CBX","TTC","MOIN","PBT","HAT","GUN","BASH","NKA","IFLT","LINX","EBET","FLIK","DP","EPY","BLAS","DFT","MEC","ENT","SMC","OCL","RAIN","STA","KLN","GRE","V","UIS","ALT","EFYT","GRWI","XLC","FYN","STU","CMPCO","DAXX","CFD","DAR","MRT","UNB","OTX","LANA","KEK","PIPL","ZET","ZER","BYC","NDC","LGD","TRUMP","BTA","ADL","XPTX","INFX","ERC20","KURT","NUKO","DGC","FCN","BRO","INSN","XPD","VISIO","TRCT","FC2","CDN","ABJ","SGR","BBP","ZENI","HTC","DAI","WHL","RC","STRC","Q2C","TRI","ATOM","I0C","SIFT","SMLY","TES","MAC","ZCG","NETKO","KLC","ADZ","PROC","ICOO","DSR","TIT","XBL","CRM","LOG","ELE","PIGGY","SAGA","UTC","EMV","MNE","JNS","MCRN","CCT","CJ","ACC","CPC","TOKEN","WGO","XIOS","NYAN","BTCS","PASL","SIGT","MNC","AU","SKIN","TROLL","BITS","CNT","XCXT","GB","FUCK","HBN","8BIT","YTN","ROC","42","MAX","B@","USC","SOON","SDRN","BTB","BPC","KOBO","RIYA","HODL","ORB","NTO","CCN","TRK","PXC","HPC","DEM","DIX","CNO","VIDZ","GAIA","DSH","RBT","ONX","OPAL","BRIT","CV2","HAL","RED","4CHN","C2","TKR","BUCKS","XPY","DRXNE","XHI","POS","ARI","TRDT","LBTC","SDC","BTCRED","CORG","WTT","TAG","ETG","ALTCOM","XJO","EVIL","KUSH","XRA","PCOIN","VOT","BCF","DDF","FNC","AMMO","BOLI","PAK","CCO","MARS","VLT","RLT","BIGUP","SPACE","MONK","CUBE","XCT","EGAS","PR","SUPER","RBX","UNY","TEK","LCP","EMD","GAP","BLC","ITI","NTWK","UNIC","JET","CCRB","GRIM","TSE","LTB","CAT","EOT","ICOB","CHESS","BTSR","COAL","MAD","888","AMS","KRONE","POST","MOJO","XGR","VAL","BITBTC","KAYI","WYV","ZZC","BSTY","DFS","MNM","PXI","EL","SLG","BERN","BTWTY","HERO","EBCH","CRX","DALC","QTL","SWING","STV","EUC","KED","TGC","VUC","MAR","ECASH","STARS","ERY","ZUR","ETHD","CMT","BAS","EREAL","SOIL","HNC","BRAT","GTC","IMS","CNNC","SHDW","BNX","ARG","SRC","GLT","BTG","PX","XVP","NRO","MAO","IETH","MOTO","XRE","MTLMC3","ICN","UNITS","HONEY","AERM","PHS","EVO","CACH","FUNC","SPEX","CON","HXX","HMP","XCO","EAGLE","611","ECO","DUO","GP","FLAX","XCRE","REE","ZMC","BITSILVER","CPN","SCORE","GPU","ACOIN","USDE","BUMBA","CXT","XCS","$$$","ARCO","RPC","MST","SPT","BLN","FIRE","JIN","SFC","BIP","TAJ","QCN","GPL","XBTS","RBIES","NEVA","RUPX","BOAT","VPRC","BENJI","MAY","SONG","OFF","ALL","CWXT","E4ROW","300","ASAFE2","BTPL","FUZZ","BSTAR","IMX","MSCN","LUNA","ICON","CTO","WBB","PLACO","COXST","SLEVIN","CTIC3","UET","CF","DRS","EXN","PEX","ARGUS","TYCHO","PIE","BITEUR","URC","PRX","PRC","PLNC","DOLLAR","BTQ","ROOFS","WOMEN","ATX","BRAIN","SOCC","GEERT","XBTC21","QBC","ZYD","LTCU","RIDE","VLTC","MILO","VIP","DIBC","LTCR","ACP","FXE","CRDNC","VRS","ELS","JS","AGLC","KNC","LIR","ZNE","LVPS","JOBS","HVCO","CTIC2","SANDG","XRC","CRTM","MGM","IBANK","NODC","P7C","VOLT","CREVA","TSTR","SLFI","NANOX","GSR","XNG","HMC","EBT","DGCS","DMB","ABN","ECA","PHO","GCN","VTA","PGL","RUSTBITS","YASH","INPAY","FIMK","ITT","CRYPT","FUNK","SHORTY","BLOCKPAY","POP","CASINO","LNK","LOT","MBI","METAL","ITZ","BXT","STS","AMBER","MRJA","BTCR","UNI","WAY","BRIA","SCRT","BLZ","GLC","GRT","BITZ","NEWB","AIB","MUT","SH","J","FRC","ISL","FLY","SLING","CYP","RMC","TALK","ICE","FRK","MEOW","WMC","SAC","VC","BITGOLD","YAC","ANTI","WORM","LEA","DLC","BOST","VEC2","WARP","GCC","URO","DES","FLVR","QBK","DBTC","BVC","MND","DRM","STEPS","BLRY","JWL","TOR","GBT","ARB","PULSE","ADCN","RSGP","G3N","EGO","BIOS","CASH","MRNG","MTM","IMPS","ORLY","BSC","DLISK","SCS","CRT","OS76","PONZI","CESC","XOC","TAGR","ALTC","CAB","SDP","BIOB","FRAZ","GBC","CCM100","LEX","CONX","SOJ","ULA","PIZZA","OCEAN","CALC","APW","ATMC","NAS","GNX","SMT","BIX","GTC","BCD","MOT","QLC","SPHTX","TSL","HTML","AMM","CAT","QBT","PRO","HPY","ACE","BCX","INF","CAPP","NGC","SHND","SBTC","ENT","MKR","DIM","B2X","FRGC","LLT","CMS","VIU","DEW","WC","UGT","XTZ","MDS","CLUB","IRL","AI","CMS","BIG","HBC","HTML5","FIL","IGNIS","EAG","GBG","BTCA","XID","ESC","BCDN","PAYP","TOK","IFC","LBTC","UQC","VASH","KBR","BSR","BTE","EXRN","XIN","GRX","UBTC","CPAY","MAGE","PLAY","KARMA","MAGN","SAFEX","ANI","SFE","QBT","FDX","SBC","ZENGOLD","TIE","GBRC","GAIN","STAR","PEC","BEST","MGC","TER","DAV","PCN","PYLNT","SHA","NEOG","PLC","ACES","WAND","SISA","MARX","SUR","MONEY","COUPE","FLAP","SIGMA","TOP","BOS","SJCX","DMC","TURBO","MSD","MINEX","ETT","MTX","CYC","VULC","ACC","THS","GAY","WIC","XSTC","LTG","BTCS","SCT","FONZ","BT1","SKR","WOW","ZBC","FAZZ","UR","DON","DAY","TRIA","HDLB","WINK","BT2","CMP","IQT","SAK","BITOK","FUDD","PLX","PRN","PNX","BTCM","MCI","EUSD","FRN","EDRC","ELITE","EVC","UAHPAY","RYZ","SKC","DUTCH","EVR","XTD","NTC","TELL","HIGH","WSX","YES","ZSE","FFC","LEPEN","RCN","HALLO","BXC","INDIA","EGOLD","COR","BLX","ASN","PRES","NAMO","UNRC","OX","GOLF","FID","APC","CYDER","GLS","GRN","RUNNERS","REGA","BTC2X","BTBc","ANTX","SND","PCS","UNC","TODAY","GMX","ABC","CHEAP","DISK","WA","PRIMU","MCR","X2","ELC","PDG","HYTV","BSN","ACN","POKE","AKY","DEUS","CASH","LAZ","SKULL","RUPX","CC","HNC","MONETA","ROYAL","QORA","MAVRO","BIRDS","FAP","TCOIN","EBIT","KASHH","LDCN","XOT","CME","BLAZR","GARY","IBTC","LKC","NBIT","SPORT","DBG","STEX","YEL","BUB","IPY","TEAM","AXIOM","PRM","ELTC2","BITCF","GML","SNAKE","UTA","9COIN","HYPER","AV","XVE","10MT","FUTC","XQN","LTH","RUBIT","BIT","TLE","SHELL","XDE2","FBL","CBD","FRWC","DASHS","DUB","MMXVI","OMC","FC","PSY","OP","TOPAZ","RICHX","SWP","TCR","HCC","TRICK","BAC","IVZ","XAU","MEN","OPES","XID","VOYA","MBL","BET","BAT","RBBT","BGR","EGG","DCRE","TESLA","TERA","RHFC","GUC","ADK","XRY","EMB","CSC","OCOW","BTU","XYLO","STC","QC","FRCT","MDC"]

//Find the input search box
let search = document.getElementById("searchCoin")

//Find every item inside the dropdown
let items = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item")
function buildDropDown(values) {
    let contents = []
    for (let name of values) {
    contents.push('<input type="button" class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="' + name + '"/>')
    }
    $('#menuItems').append(contents.join(""))

    //Hide the row that shows no items were found
    $('#empty').hide()
}

//Capture the event when user types into the search box
window.addEventListener('input', function () {
    filter(search.value.trim().toLowerCase())
})

//For every word entered by the user, check if the symbol starts with that word
//If it does show the symbol, else hide it
function filter(word) {
    let length = items.length
    let collection = []
    let hidden = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (items[i].value.toLowerCase().startsWith(word)) {
        $(items[i]).show()
    }
    else {
        $(items[i]).hide()
        hidden++
    }
    }

    //If all items are hidden, show the empty view
    if (hidden === length) {
    $('#empty').show()
    }
    else {
    $('#empty').hide()
    }
}

//If the user clicks on any item, set the title of the button as the text of the item
$('#menuItems').on('click', '.dropdown-item', function(){
    $('#dropdown_coins').text($(this)[0].value)
    $("#dropdown_coins").dropdown('toggle');
})

buildDropDown(names)
```

```css
.dropdown {
  margin: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
   
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown_coins" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false">
        Coin
    </button>
    <div id="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_coins">
        <form class="px-4 py-2">
            <input type="search" class="form-control" id="searchCoin" placeholder="BTC" autofocus="autofocus">
        </form>
        <div id="menuItems"></div>
        <div id="empty" class="dropdown-header">No coins found</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1**

The code above uses show() and hide() inside a loop which is why the UI is slow when you clear everything you typed in case you didn't notice. Instead of that, use .css({display: 'none'}) and .css({display: 'block'})

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks!!

Answer (score 22):

As of version 1.13.1 there is support for Bootstrap 4:
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

The implementation remains exactly the same as it was in Bootstrap 3:

- add class="selectpicker" and data-live-search="true"to your select
- add data-tokens to your options. The live search will look into these data-token element when performing the search.

This is an example, taken from the site of the link above:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

Live search for the search term 'fro' will only leave the third option visible (because of the data-tokens "frosting").

Don't forget to include the bootstrap-select CDN .css and .js in your project.
I am very glad to see this live search become available again, because it comes in very handy when presenting large dropdown lists to the user.

Comment: Nice project! There is a live demo here: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/ and checkout their Github for a version for Bootstrap 5: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select

Comment: this does not seem to work any longer.  has this changed?

Answer (score 14):

I took the answer from [PirateApp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5371505/pirateapp) and made it reusable. If you include this script it will transform all selects with the class '.dropdown' to searchable dropdowns.

```js
$('.dropdown').each(function(index, dropdown) {

  //Find the input search box
  let search = $(dropdown).find('.search');

  //Find every item inside the dropdown
  let items = $(dropdown).find('.dropdown-item');

  //Capture the event when user types into the search box
  $(search).on('input', function() {
    filter($(search).val().trim().toLowerCase())
  });

  //For every word entered by the user, check if the symbol starts with that word
  //If it does show the symbol, else hide it
  function filter(word) {
    let length = items.length
    let collection = []
    let hidden = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (items[i].value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(word)) {
        $(items[i]).show()
      } else {
        $(items[i]).hide()
        hidden++
      }
    }

    //If all items are hidden, show the empty view
    if (hidden === length) {
      $(dropdown).find('.dropdown_empty').show();
    } else {
      $(dropdown).find('.dropdown_empty').hide();
    }
  }

  //If the user clicks on any item, set the title of the button as the text of the item
  $(dropdown).find('.dropdown-menu').find('.menuItems').on('click', '.dropdown-item', function() {
    $(dropdown).find('.dropdown-toggle').text($(this)[0].value);
    $(dropdown).find('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Benutzer
    </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_user">
    <form class="px-4 py-2">
      <input type="search" class="form-control search" placeholder="Suche.." autofocus="autofocus">
    </form>
    <div class="menuItems">
      <input type="button" class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="Test1" />
      <input type="button" class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="Test2" />
      <input type="button" class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="Test3" />
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;" class="dropdown-header dropdown_empty">No entry found</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a `.toString()` to the `toLowerCase()` in the for loop, maybe you can add it to your answer?

Answer (score 7):

As of 10. July 2017, the issue of [Bootstrap 4 support with `bootstrap-select` is still open](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1135). In the open issue, there are some ad-hoc solutions which you could try with your project.

Or you could use a library like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) and add a theme to match Bootstrap 4. Here is an example: [Select 2 with Bootstrap 4](http://avladov.com/blog/494/select2-with-bootstrap4) (*disclaimer: I'm not the author of this blog post and I haven't verified if this still works with the all versions of Bootstrap 4*).

Comment: [Apr 19, 2018 - Bootstrap 4 support has officially been added in v1.13.0!](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1135#issuecomment-382780838)

Answer (score 3):

### dropdown with search using bootstrap 4.4.0 version

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div
    = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i <
    a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">home</a>
    <a href="#base">contact</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution, I suggest change variable names lile `myInput` to a meaningfull name that can be used everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/) to manage your popup.
It comes [bundled with Bootstrap or you can use it
separately](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).

This is a very rough example and how you want to hide/show the popup
is your choice.

```js
const popupReference = document.getElementById('popup-reference');
const popup = document.getElementById('popup')
const popper = Popper.createPopper(
  popupReference, popup, {
    placement: 'bottom-start',
    modifiers: [
          {
            name: 'offset',
            options: {
              offset: [0, 2],
            },
          },
        ],
  }
)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="m-3">
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap" >
      <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
</svg>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="popup-reference" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search" value="Item">

    </div>

    <div class="list-group shadow" id="popup">
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" aria-current="true">
    The first item
  </button>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A second item</button>
      <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A third button item</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```