# How to create Bootstrap 4 searchable dropdown box having dynamic options

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I would like to know how to create searchable dropdown menu in bootstrap 4 using javascript(not jquery) with dynamic options
[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select class="FormDropDown " id="countries" name="countries">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="4">SG</option>
    <option value="5">TH</option>
    <option value="6">MY</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you open to using a library for that? Or are you asking for a native solution to doing it?

Comment: @wentjun  thanks for reply,Native solution javascript because i am not allowed to use jquery package in my scenario

Comment: I see.. In that case you could do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007712/bootstrap-4-dropdown-with-search