# Huge dropdown list and multi select boxes

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, dropdown

I have xml file and select list.I'm creating options using loop.Problem is xml data have +5000 options.And I've 20-30 select box.and when i use xml data inside of loop +5000 xml data repeating 20-30 times.Its become so slow.How can i load that huge dropdown list 1 time for all select boxes ?

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file('options.xml');
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("selections.xml");
$xmltotal1 = $xml1->selections->count();
$xmltotal2 = $xml2->options->count();

for ($z = 0; $z < $xmltotal1; $z++) {
    echo "<select>";

    for ($s = 0; $s < $xmltotal2; $s++) {

        echo "<option>" . $xml2->options->name . "</option>";

    }

    echo "</select>";
}
```

This is example of my codes.Also i can export xml files as json.I must make it fast.Someone can show me any way ?Dropdown list doesn't need appear in select box.Select box can keep search bar.(ex:Select2)But i don't know anyway for mark all select boxes to one data input.Someone can help me ?

Comment: Possibly consider organizing how you want to have such options, strategically. 5000+ options on a drop down makes little UI/UX sense.

Comment: put some pagination in place. When the user start typing some letters fetch the matching result. There plugin like select2 or similar that wrap all the js needed for that

Comment: I would advise that you convert the dropdown data into JSON (Simply do a Google search, you could even do it in PHP). For UI/UX, have a look at some answers on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007712/bootstrap-4-dropdown-with-search

Comment: okay thank you https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays i found what i wanted exactly but i must try it.